# What is the coding behind system calls?

Tags: kernel, system, processor

I'm currently working on a design project that at it's basic form involves changing the frequencies on the different processors to optimize performance.  It's essentially observing how governor's perform and then quantifying the results. Pretty straight forward.

One of the advisers for the project wants my partner and I to provide a more detailed **explanation** of the **system calls**.

My understanding is that since the system calls are making changes within the kernel that it's done mostly through hardware.

My adviser believes that the system calls are actually directories.  If that is the case where can I access these directories to examine the code?

For example, can someone explain to me exactly what is being called for this:
system `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq`

Thanks for any information provided.

Comment: Thanks.  I've browsed these sites for awhile and wasn't sure where exactly to post it.  It's on the Android platform specifically, but you're right that there's a larger pool of programmers on the main site.

Comment: To me it was not clear you specifically targeted the Android platform with your question -- as the example you gave also matches Linux/Unix. Sometimes it's hard to decide for the best place, 100% agreed. I already marked your question for migration, but it requires some approval as I'm no moderator -- hence the hint to the "flag" link directly below your question. Keep in mind that Android uses a Linux kernel, so that's where "system calls" go to ;)